# How do I find strings with a mix of \x20 \t and \xA0 in 2 places, replace both with \xA0 (and not finding completed ones) with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I want to search this pattern:

Example 1.:
`1 Joh 3`
Example 2.
`1 Joh 3,5`

Usually blank spaces are single \x20 but they can be any kind of spaces (narrow no break space, narrow space, space, tabs etc.) and not necessarily single.
I want to replace spaces with \xA0 where absent.

To do this, here is what I use:

Find:
`([0-9]{1,}+)([^\xA0])([a-z]{1,}+)([^\xA0])([0-9]{1,})(\,)*([\s]*)([0-9]{1,})*`

Replace:
`$1 $3 $5$6$8`

This works, but it finds not only strings where the substitution has partially been done, (which is what I want to make sure I do not miss those cases where the user has applied one \xA0), but also strings where the substitution has fully been done, which I do not want.

So, the question is: How does one search exclusively for:
`1\xa0Joh\s3`
`1\tJoh\xa03`
`1\xa0Joh\s3,6`
`1\sJoh\xa03,6`

and of course:

`1\sJoh\s3,6`

and not:

`1\xa0Joh\xa03`
`1\xa0Joh\xa03,6`

All of these are to be found within a text. For example:
Lorem ipsum dolor 1 Joh 2,41 sit amet, consectetur (1 Joh 3) adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor [3 Joh 2,41] incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo_consequat.

Where
1\sJoh\Ax02,41
1\Ax0Joh\s3
3\sJoh\s2,41

In the end, the result should always be:

```
1\xA0Joh\Ax02,41
1\xA0Joh\xA03
3\xA0Joh\xA02,41
```

Or, using the real example above with the expected results (all white spaces in the replaced expression are now \xA0):

Lorem ipsum dolor 1 Joh 2,41 sit amet, consectetur (1 Joh 3) adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor [3 Joh 2,41] incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo_consequat.

I tried to change your regex in order to make non capture groups, capture groups and I grouped all elements in order to paste them in the replace string:

```
(\d+)((?=(\xA0)?)\s+)([a-z]+)(?!\1)(\s)(\d+)(,\d+)*
```

Replace:

`$1 $3 $6$7`

However it does not work as desired because

1. the ([a-z]+) group disappears and I get `3 2,41` instead of `3 Joh 2,41`
2. Also, it keeps finding the strings where both \xA0 have already been replaced such as `3 Joh 2,41`, (with both \xA0) which I would like to avoid.

Can you see what is wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Which utility and operating system are you using?

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, here is the answer:
Version: 7.1.8.1 / LibreOffice Community
CPU threads: 8; OS: Mac OS X 10.16; UI render: default; VCL: osx
Locale: it-IT (it.UTF-8); UI: en-US
Calc: threaded

Answer (score 0):

**Update according to clarification**

- Find: `(\d+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*)`
- Replace: `$1\xAO$2\xA0$3`

**Explanation:**

```
(\d+)           # group 1, 1 or more digits
\s+             # 1 or more any kind of white spaces
([a-z]+)        # group 2, 1 or more letters
\s+             # 1 or more any kind of white spaces
(               # group 3
    \d+             # 1 or more digits
    (?:,\d+)*       # non capture group, a comma followeed by 1 or more digits, may appear 0 or more times
)               # end group 3
```

Comment: Thank you, @toto! I noticed that my question is not exact in two ways: 1. these strings are found within paragraphs: Ex. text 1 Joh 4,53 text.
2. The replacement regex is as important as the first one. 
So I modified your regex in order to make non capture groups, capture groups and I put some more elements in the groups in order to use them later: (\d+)((?=(\xA0)?)\s+)([a-z]+)(?!\1)(\s)(\d+)(,\d+)* Replace: $1 $3 $6$7 however it does not work –(the ([a-z]+) group disappears (1   4,53)– and now it also finds strings with both \xA0 Can you see what is wrong?

Comment: @Earendil: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1704003/edit) and add sample text **and** expected result.

Comment: I did, @Toto thanks!

Comment: @Earendil: It's not really clear what your question is but may be something like:  Find:`(\d+)\s+([a-z]{3})\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*) ` Replace:`$1\xA0$2\xA0$3` should work.

Comment: Thank you. @Toto, The Regex is a lot neater than what I started with. I changed it a bit into: `(\d+)\s+([a-z]{1,})\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)*)*` in order to find cases like this one: `(1 Macc 3)`.


So, it works, however it also finds the cases where the substitution has already been done completely  `3\xA0Joh\xA02,41`. I suppose there is no way to make it find only `3\xA0Joh\s2,41`, `3\sJoh\xA02,41`, `3\sJoh\s2,41`. Thank you anyway for your time and efforts.

Comment: `([a-z]{1,})` is better written as `([a-z]+)`, the last `*` in your regex doesn't make sense unless you have some text like `3\xA0Joh\s2,41,123,456,789`, remove it. It's really simpler to match string with 2 `\xA0` and it isn't  too bad for efficiency. if it's OK for you, I'll change my answer with this new regex.

Comment: Thank you Toto, what you say makes sense, I'll adopt both suggestions! Please go ahead and change your answer. Thanks a lot again for your time.

Comment: @Earendil: It's already done. You may accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Please forgive me, but accepting the answer would not faithfully reflect the question. Let's see if we can give an answer to the initial question, shall we? 
So, since a single regex is not possible, maybe two can reach the same result, i.e. finding only cases where there are replacements left, what do you think?
This is what came to my mind: Regex 1
`(\d+)(\s+)([a-z]+)([^\xA0])(\d+(?:,\d+)*)`
Regex 2:
`(\d+)([^\xA0])([a-z]+)(\s+)(\d+(?:,\d+)*)`
Replacement for both:
`$1 $3 $5`
What do you think?